# crosscompile full mono with Android NDK

Tags: c#, android-ndk, mono

I'm trying to compile full mono to run on an (rooted) Android device. I need this, because I want to port an application from Embedded Linux to Android. The Software runs on an embedded linux device at the moment... I really want to reuse the Software as it is without rewriting parts of it...

What I've done so far:

-Installed a Linux Debian

-Installed the Android SDK NDK as of http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html

-Downloaded the MONO Tarball (I already tried different versions 4.6, 4.8 and 5.0)

-run following commands:

```
export CC=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
 export CXX=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
 export CPP=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
 export AR=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
 export AS=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as
 export ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain

./configure --prefix=/home/alex/Android/monobuild/ --with-sigaltstack=no --with-mcs-docs=no --disable-mcs-build --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-nls --with-sysroot=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain/sysroot/ --cache=/home/alex/Android/my.cache

make

-->
CC libmonoruntimesgen_la-w32file-unix-glob.lo
CC libmonoruntimesgen_la-w32error-unix.lo

CC ../../support/libm/libmonoruntimesgen_la-complex.lo
../../support/libm/complex.c:19:26: fatal error: math_private.h: No such file or Directory #include "math_private.h"

 compilation terminated.
 Makefile:4173: recipe for target '../../support/libm/libmonoruntimesgen_la-complex.lo' failed
 make[3]: *** [../../support/libm/libmonoruntimesgen_la-complex.lo] Error 1
 make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-5.0.0/mono/metadata'
 Makefile:446: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
 make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-5.0.0/mono'
 Makefile:522: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-5.0.0'
 Makefile:451: recipe for target 'all' failed
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

In the mono configure script I saw lots things about Android, so I assume that it must be possible to crosscompile. Anybody there who knows more details about the errors?

I can copy the file math_private.h from the NDK Directory to the mono Directory, but then it breaks at a later stage:

```
Making all in mini
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1/mono/mini'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1/mono/mini'
  CCLD     mono-sgen
./.libs/libmonosgen-2.0.so: error: undefined reference to 'tkill'
main.c:172: error: undefined reference to 'mono_dl_open'
main.c:179: error: undefined reference to 'mono_loader_register_module'
main.c:339: error: undefined reference to 'mono_build_date'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1468: recipe for target 'mono-sgen' failed
make[4]: *** [mono-sgen] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1/mono/mini'
Makefile:1293: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1/mono/mini'
Makefile:445: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1/mono'
Makefile:525: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1'
Makefile:454: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Is `math_private.h` part of the project you're building? It isn't a part of the NDK, and I don't believe it's part of any C libraries public interface. If it's a part of mono and that isn't getting included, I suspect there's something wrong with their makefiles. Are you able to build the same source for your host machine (not cross compiling)?

Comment: I found the file in the NDK: ./Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/support/src/msun/math_private.h but I'm not sure if just copying the file is correct. Anyway, if I copy the file, then later I get another error: 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/alex/Android/mono-4.8.1/mono/mini'
  CCLD     mono-sgen
./.libs/libmonosgen-2.0.so: error: undefined reference to 'tkill'
main.c:172: error: undefined reference to 'mono_dl_open'
main.c:179: error: undefined reference to 'mono_loader_register_module'
main.c:339: error: undefined reference to 'mono_build_date'

Comment: No, copying that file isn't correct.

Comment: an further suggestions? the mono framework compiles fine on many other platforms, so it seems there are no files missing in the mono project...

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some trouble and use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html). It will take care of the headache of using autoconf with the NDK for you.

Comment: Thanks - I already tried this and my results above are already with the standalone toolchain:

make-standalone-toolchain.sh --arch=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --platform=android-23 --install-dir=/home/alex/Android/mytoolchain